# React Hook useEffect has a missing dependency for the setter of useState in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I understand, that `useEffect` requires his dependencies in the dependency array, but when I combine this with `useState` I will have an infinite loop:

```js
const [valid, setValid] = useState(false);

useEffect(() => {
   setValid(true);
}, [valid]};
```

This is why I'm using it like:

```
useEffect(() => {
   setValid(true);
}, []};
```

Thus, I get:

```
React Hook useEffect has a missing dependency: 'setValid'.
```

How can I get rid of the warning?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can safely add this dependency to your `useEffect`. React guarantees the same function identity at each render.

From React Docs:

> React guarantees that setState function identity is stable and won’t change on re-renders. This is why it’s safe to omit from the `useEffect` or `useCallback`  dependency list.

Therefore, even if you add to your dependency it won't trigger any unexpected calls.

You can use the [react-hooks eslint plugin](https://github.com/facebook/react/tree/master/packages/eslint-plugin-react-hooks) by Dan Abramov and disable the rule if you want to disable the warning. But I wouldn't recommend it. This plugin can save you from a lot of mistakes

Now, to the second part of the question, you are setting the state in the same `useEffect` that is going to trigger the callback when that state value changes.

Your `useEffect` keeps calling itself in an infinite loop.

Therefore, the correct solution would be to:

```
useEffect(() => {
    setValid(value)
}, [setValid])
```

Answer (score 1):

Please try adding setValid to dependency array instead of valid :

```
const [valid, setValid] = useState(false);

useEffect(() => {
   setValid(true);
}, [setValid]};
```